# What does trying to say means

Tags: reading

Like if someone asks what is the writer / author trying to say, does it mean trying as in the definition attempt or effort? Can someone please explain in a clear way with examples.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/try), the main meaning of **try** is "to attempt to do something".

If you were having a party and you were unable to contact one of your friends to invite them, you would say "I tried to contact her". This states that you did attempt to contact her, and also implies that you failed.

After an earthquake, you might want to contact your parents to make sure that they are OK: you would say "I am trying to contact my parents". The use of the present participle **trying** states that you have already made several failed attempts, and you are still trying.

If you ask the question "What does [Author] say?", you are asking about the literal meaning of the words on the page.

By contrast, "What is [Author] trying to say?" uses the present participle **trying**: this suggests that the author's main message is perhaps not perfectly clear, most likely because it is a [subtext](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/subtext). Here is an example:

> What Eliot is trying to say cannot be paraphrased, reduced to a prose equivalent, or made into a message. For it is in the relationship of all the different fields of experience that are brought together in the poem that its full significance lies ... - *T.S.Eliot, Muriel Clara Bradbrook 1965*

Note that the expression *What are **you** trying to say?" can also be used when you think that somebody is implying something unkind or untrue.

Answer (score 0):

That's precisely it.

In baseball, as the batter, you can exert effort (try) to hit the pitch, but you may not succeed.

As a cook, you can exert effort (try) to make some pasta, but it can fail (or succeed).

In communication, the "hitting the ball", or "making the pasta", is "getting you to understand". So "what the writer is trying to say" is like "what the author is exerting effort to make you understand".

I hope you understand what I'm trying to say :)